# Messages don’t always appear in Mail.app

Tags: imap, apple-mail

I asked this question on serverfault, but it was correctly suggested that superuser is better -- and I agree:

My wife and I share a Mac and use different accounts. We both use Apple's standard Mail.app. We can also get to our email accounts via SquirrelMail that our webhost provides. Both SquirrelMail and Mail.app are connecting via IMAP.

My wife was the first to notice that not all messages were getting to the Mail.app. She would check the Mac (our main machine) and then a little while later check mail from another machine via SquirrelMail and see messages there that should have been on the Mac. She would go back and those messages would never show up.

Lately, I have been seeing the same thing, though less often. I can't reproduce it, or just look at a message to see if they haven't been moved over. I've looked in Junk, etc. and the Mac simply never sees those messages via IMAP.

Does anyone have a guess to something I could poke around at?

Comment: I got  answer from MacLemon on serverfault -- haven't tried it yet.

Did you try a manual resyncing of the account in Mail.app by going to the Mailbox menu and then choose Synchronize all accounts? Is it possible that you're moving the messages in Mail.app to a local only Mailbox instead of a Mailbox that resides on the IMAP server?

Comment: I tried the resync and it seems better for me. I need to confer with my other half to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried rebuilding the mailbox?

Select the offending mailbox from the list on the left and from the menu, select **Mailbox** > **Rebuild**

Repeat as needed for other mailboxes.

Comment: After a few rebuilds, this hasn't happened in a while. So I guess this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) or another mail application to see if the problem persist?

I know this is not solution, but it could possibly help you figure out if the problem lies with Mail.app or the server.

Comment: I get your drift.

My theory is that if it works with SquirrelMail, then it may not be the IMAP. I could try with fetchmail -- that's would be less overhead than all of Thunderbird.

Comment: I didn't read your post all that well, I see... missed out on the SquirrelMail